# How to fix action_controller/metal/responder (LoadError) in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I installed the jasper-rails gem and this error showed when im starting rails server. I am using the latest version of ruby and rails on windows. How do i fix this?

```
c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jasper-rails-1.0.3/lib/jasper-rails.rb:26:in `require': cannot load such file -- action_controller/metal/responder (LoadError)
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/jasper-rails-1.0.3/lib/jasper-rails.rb:26:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:91:in `block (2 levels) in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:86:in `block in require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `each'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:75:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/bundler-1.13.7/lib/bundler.rb:106:in `require'
        from c:/Users/cjhmonteclaro/Desktop/Execute/config/application.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `require'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:88:in `block in server'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `tap'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:85:in `server'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:49:in `run_command!'
        from c:/RailsInstaller/Ruby2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/railties-5.0.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from bin/rails:4:in `require'
        from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
```

Comment: This gem is not updated since a long time. `responder` was removed from Rails in 4.x . So either Use Rails 3.2 or maybe you can try and use [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/responders) gem. I think that will provide the missing `responder`.

Comment: it still dont work :(

Comment: Then you might have to use any alternative. That gem is outdated.

Comment: yes thank you @Sajan